# How can I loop through the next batch file in a for loop with some sql code

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, sqlcmd

I am attempting to write a batch code that loops through a folder `C:\XYZ` with a list of `.bat` files. I want the code to loop through each `.bat` file in the folder, *(which uploads some data into MSQL Server)*, and performs some SQL code on each `.bat` file, before looping back to the next `.bat` file and so on.

My code so far loops through all the `.bat` files then performs the SQL code, but I want instead to perform the SQL code on each `bat` file before looping to the next one.

This is for MSQL Server using SQLCMD Utility embedded in a windows batch file using a `for` loop. The problem is with my syntax, I just don't know how to get the logic to loop through each `.bat` file.

This loops through all `.bat` files then performs SQL on them...

```
CD "C:\XYZ"  
for /r %%i in (.\*.bat) do Call %%i  
SQLCMD -S ABC\SQLEXPRESS -E -d database -q "Some SQL code"
```

While this does the first iteration, (only 1 file), of what I actually want to happen, but fails to loop through the other `.bat` files.

```
CD "C:\XYZ"  
for /r %%i in (.\*.bat) do  (  
    Call %%i
    SQLCMD -S ABC\SQLEXPRESS -E -d database -q "Some SQL code"  
)
```

I'd like to also know a log of the time it takes to run through each batch file in the loop and when it terminates in the command window.

Comment: you had it, just remove the `/r` in your `for` command.

Comment: @Greg Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work (in the second block of code). It still just executes the first .bat file in the folder and runs the SQL code on it, failing to loop through the next .bat file.

Comment: it works for me, exactly how you have it, but without the `/r`. is there something in the very first bat file that is causing the loop to break? I assume the batch files don't have spaces in the name, if they do, best to wrap in double quotes `call "%%I"`

Comment: @Greg....I just figured it out.....it was my SQLCMD code....I had to use a "-Q" instead of a "-q"....that way, it exits the SQL code and re-loops to the next file, otherwise with just "-q" it gets hung up on the first batch file.

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem I had was with the SQLCMD code...the solution was to use a "-Q" instead of a "-q", that way it exits the SQL code and loops to the next batch file, otherwise it gets hung up on the first batch file.

[More details on SQLCMD syntax here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-2017)